# Parse and change elements from database to the XML file

Tags: mysql, xml

I got XML `items.xml` file with (almost) the same values as my `items` table has, I mean fe. there is a field in the `items` table: `level` and for any `id` the `level` is set to 144, but in the XML file, the `level=` attribute is set to `"1"` (for the same `id`) - what is the best way to correct values like this?

It should go like this:

> - Check value `level` in the database table for any id.
> - If the `level` value from the database is other than the `level=""` attribute for this ID, set it to the same `level` value as in the
>     database.

It can be kinda hard, since there is about ~40000 records to check.

I will appreciate some examples also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what programming-language you are using, find the corresponding StAX-implementation. For Java I would go with `XMLStreamReader` ([JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html)) and `XMLStreamWriter` ([JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html)). You should find some tutorials on the internet.

When you encounter the `START_ELEMENT` event while reading the XML, check the tag's name (`getLocalName()`). If you are on the correct tag, check for the attributes, i.e. using the `getAttribute...()`-methods and handle the writing differently.

Along all of this, use an `XMLStreamWriter` to write your new XML to some `OutputStream`. After all, just write the `OutputStream` to whereever you wish (File, etc.).

Don't forget to read your Input-XML using a `BufferedInputStream` (or some other buffered way).

Good luck!

P.S.: You can also use `XMLEventReader` or `XMLEventWriter`, but personally I prefer `XMLStreamReader` / `XMLStreamWriter`. Also, you could use different StAX-Implementations like `Woodstox`.

P.P.S.: For PHP use XMLReader and XMLWriter. See [here](http://p0l0.binware.org/index.php/2011/07/04/simplexml-vs-xmlwriter-vs-dom/).

Comment: I'd use PHP, because I know this language pretty good, thank you for examples I'll give it a try.